# Matlab FFT2 transform the result into an isotropic direction

Tags: matlab, fft

How to Transform the amplitude of Fourrier C(k,l) in an isotropic direction K where K is the module of (k,l):

1-I have a matrix M(x,y) ;

2-I transform this matrix into Mfft(k,l)

3-Now what i want is to transform the Mfft(k,l) into a vector V(K) where K is the module of (k,l)

Any help would be great :)

Thank u guys;

Adam

Comment: What's an _isotropic direction_? And the _module_ of a pair of numbers?

Comment: isotropic is in one direction , the module of (k,l) is the norm of two this pair of two vectors not number